# Dynamically Adding a Context Menu Item with a Click Handler in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list view with a context menu. I am looking to dynamically add an item which has a click event. As you can see below, doing it statically is pretty straight forward in the XAML. However, when I try to do this in C# it will not compile. I've checked several existing StackOverflow questions, but they seem to be using different controls or are for WinForms instead.

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="10,7,10,8">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem x:Name="Test" Header="Test" Click="Test"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
<ListView.View>
```

ModuleName is the name and DisplayModule() is the click handler event I want.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
var menuItem = new MenuItem();
menuItem.Name = ModuleName;
menuItem.Header = null;
menuItem.Click += DisplayModule;
listView.ContextMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
```

Comment: I actually had tried doing that, but I was doing it like this https://imgur.com/a/Iz3BNMu

And it wouldn't let me add the Click. But declaring it how you did allowed me to access the Click property. Seems to work!